# Are my exponential family functions correct?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ denote a random sample from the PDF

$$f_{\varphi}(x)=
\begin{cases}
 \varphi x^{\varphi - 1} &\text{if}\, 0 < x < 1, \varphi > 0\\
      0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

This density function is a member of the one-parameter exponential family.

The one-parameter exponential family is $f(x) = \exp\{c(\theta) T(y) + d(\theta) + S(y)\}$.

I rewrite the PDF as

$$f_\varphi(x) = \varphi \exp\{ (\varphi - 1) \ln(x) \}$$

So shouldn't we have the functions $c(\varphi) = \varphi - 1$, $T(x) = \ln(y)$, $d(\varphi) = \varphi$, and $S(y) = 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For exponential families of the form

$$f(x)=\exp\left\{c(\theta)T(x)+d(\theta)+S(x)\right\}$$

we can write the given density as $$\exp\left\{\log \varphi + (\varphi - 1)\log x\right\}$$

so $c(\varphi)=\varphi -1,T(x)=\log x,d(\varphi)=\log \varphi,S(x)=0$. Canonical form for a single parameter exponential family is when $c(\theta)=\theta$ so we can put the density in canonical form as so $\exp\left\{\log \varphi+\varphi \log x-\log x\right\}$ with $c(\varphi)=\varphi,T(x)=\log x, S(x)=-\log x, d(\varphi)=\log \varphi$.

An alternate form often used is $h(x)g(\theta)\exp(\eta(\theta)\cdot T(x))$ and here it would be $\varphi\exp\left[(\varphi-1)\log x\right]$ or in canonical form, $\varphi\frac 1 x\exp\left[\varphi\log x\right]$.

Comment: Ahh, ok, that's what I was missing. It was said that $\sum_{i = 1}^n -\log(X_i)$ is sufficient for $\varphi$, so I didn't understand what was going on. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome!